# how to do the concurrent version of List.map in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to implement the concurrent version of List.map function in Ocaml. I know there is a similar function in module Async.Std.Deferred.List, but here I am just trying to attack this myself.

Here is what I have:

```
let deferred_listmap (f : 'a -> 'b Deferred.t) (l : 'a list) =
let f' acc elem =
    (f elem) >>= fun s ->
    return (acc@[s]) in
List.fold_left f' [] l
```

And obviously there is a type matching error here, since fold_left requires a function f with type ('b list -> 'a -> 'b list), while the f' I have here is of type ('b list -> 'a -> 'b list Deferred.t). But for this I cannot help since I am using a bind(>>=) here which expects the return type of its function argument to be a deferred type. So I am getting kind of a contradiction here, and I cannot think of other uses on bind or folds or other functions in List module to solve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you are using libraries coming separately from the Ocaml compiler, perhaps you should indicate that?

Comment: Now, if you are using `Async` utilities to reimplement this function, I suppose that `Async.Std.Deferred.all` would be handy (and is most certainly what the real function uses). That function in turn may be implemented using a fold of `both` (in the same module) on the list.

Comment: Obviously it depends what do you mean with concurrent. Should every map be done on another thread? (Like the example from @Oleg) Or should it be done in chunks of n items? In order to answer more details are needed

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try with the `Thread` and `Event` Modules .

```
open Thread
open Event

let tapply f ls = 
    let res = 
        List.map (fun e ->  
        let c = new_channel () in 
        let _ = create (fun c -> send c (f e) |> sync) c in
        receive c) ls in
        List.map sync res
```

example :

```
# tapply (fun e -> delay 3.0; e*e) [17;573;2;6;3];;
- : int list = [289; 328329; 4; 36; 9] (*waiting time only 3 sec, not 15*)
```